# Webservice/API to grab a screenshot of another website? (known solutions are too slow)

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, api, screenshot

From this question:-

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1342611/is-there-a-webservice-api-to-grab-a-screenshot-of-another-website

and some other questions/google I got some results like:--

- http://www.bitpixels.com/    ( limitations:- only thumbnails, max size is 200*200 pixels)
- http://www.thumbalizr.com/   (Limitations:-- No css formatting.)
- http://www.webshotspro.com/   (Limitations:-- too slow, even pro account is too slow.)

Can you suggest me something really fast and powerful. I am ready to pay for it. Isnt google providing any api for it? as they are showing screenshots in results.

**EDIT**:-- Also I need something which capture complete home page. Not just one screen.

Comment: urlbox.io - screenshot as a service. Its got easy to integrate API and extremely fast and reliable service.

Comment: Looked at those and then found http://gograb.it which was faster and free at the level I'm using it.

Comment: There is this [url to image API](https://apiflash.com/) that could work well for your problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

wkhmltopdf is the best API I've seen so far for that kind of stuff. it uses the Webkit rendering engine.

http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/

http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/wiki/IntegrationWithPhp

**Here's the manual for wkhtmltoimage:**

http://madalgo.au.dk/~jakobt/wkhtmltoxdoc/wkhtmltoimage_0.10.0_rc2-doc.html

Following **SleepyCod** lead. I got the solution.

Following these links you can setup a high quality pdf's 
gems and plugins installation guide.

- https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew
- https://github.com/jdpace/PDFKit/wiki/Installing-WKHTMLTOPDF
- https://github.com/jdpace/PDFKit

Same way you can generate PNG's too. :-)

Comment: Please confirm my edit part so that community can take benefit from this.

Answer (score 4):

You can take a look at [Browshot](https://browshot.com/) for real-time screenshots of any website. It can be used to capture the screen or the whole page. You can create a free accounts and try free screenshots. No limitation on the thumbnail size.

Answer (score 1):

There is also a JavaScript library which is able to capture a screenshot of websites. I used it once and it was pretty handy. Take a look at it [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this one:
http://immediatenet.com/thumbnail_api.html
cached entries are fetched fast, and new requests pretty much immediately.
There's a way to get complete pages also:
http://immediatenet.com/HTML2image.html
but there is no known API for that yet (rumours are that there will be one though)
The greatest thing is that you can even request own API:s if existing ones aren't ok.